# Why regular expression .* is slower at one place and faster at other

Tags: regex

Lately I am using a lot of regular expressions in java/groovy. For testing I routinely use [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/). Obviously I am looking at the regular expressions performance too.

One thing I noticed that using `.*` properly can significantly improve the overall performance. Primarily, using `.*` in between, or better to say not at the end of the regular expression is performance kill.

For example, in [this](https://www.regex101.com/r/iM7nI9/1) regular expression the required number of steps is 27:

[image]

[If I change first `.*` to `\s*`](https://www.regex101.com/r/cA6yA5/1), it will reduce the steps required significantly to 16:

[image]

However, [if I change second `.*` to `\s*`](https://www.regex101.com/r/uU6qP6/1), it does not reduce the steps any further:

[image]

I have few questions:

1. Why the above? *I dont want to compare `\s` and `.*`. I know the difference. I want to know why `\s` and `.*` costs different based on their position in the complete regex. And then the characteristics of the regex which may cost different based on their position in the overall regex (or based on any other aspect other than position, if there is any).*
2. Does the steps counter given in this site really gives any indication about regex performance?
3. what other simple or similar (position related) regex performance observations you have?

Comment: You should read more about backtracking. `.` matches `m`, `a`, etc., and `\s` does not (it only matches whitespace). At the end, `\s*` and `.*` work just the same here. I wonder if this type of question is off-topic.

Comment: @stribizhev I think OP understands what `.` means. The question is why `\s` is more performant conditionally.

Comment: It has all been explained before, I can't find exact post though. The keyword is backtracking.

Comment: but then at one place matching `m`,`a` etc. cause more steps and at the end of the regular expression it causes least (1) steps. Its not about comparing `\s` and `.*`, its about position of `.*`. And then am asking if there are other regex elements that cost different based on their position in the regex

Comment: @erip yes or we can say `.*` is performant conditionally. And then characteristics of such regexes which perform conditionally based on their position in complete regex (or on aspect other than mere position)

Comment: use the debugger of regex101 to see what happens.

Comment: Oh, yes, look-arounds cost differently at specific positions. After an anchor `^`, a look-ahead is less costly but in some cases it should be unanchored.

Comment: I suggest you to look at the debugger in regex101. With `.*` in the first case regex tries to match all the text and then backtracks untill it find matching string

Comment: Generalizing: the quantified subpatterns that can match one another should not go one after another.

Comment: @stribizhev seems that your generalization should make more sense to me, but it isnt. Can you explain more? Give some more examples following that generalization? Or point to the reference/book discussing the same? I am quite good at CS theory. So I may understand if the reference is more theoretical.

Comment: thanks all here, yes I realize from debugger backtracking is the only reason in this case

Comment: A [version with 20k steps](https://regex101.com/r/hI4iK4/1) but only [20 steps with \s](https://regex101.com/r/hI4iK4/2)

Comment: Please note that that `.*` and `\s*` at the end in your example are both useless.  They will always match, no matter what.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way regex engines work with the `*` quantifier, aka *greedy* quantifier, is to consume everything in the input that matches, then:

1. try the next term in the regex. If it matches, proceed on
2. "unconsume" one character (move the pointer back one), aka *backtrack* and goto step 1.

Since `.` matches anything (almost), the first state after encountering `.*` is to move the pointer to the end of input, then start moving back through the input one char at a time trying the next term until there's a match.

With `\s*`, only whitespace is consumed, so the pointer is initially moved exactly where you want it to be - no backtracking required to match the next term.

Something you should try is using the *reluctant* quantifier `.*?`, which will consume one char at a time until the next term matches, which should have the same time complexity as `\s*`, but be slightly more efficient because no check of the current char is required.

`\s*` and `.*` at the *end* of the expression will perform similarly, because both will consume everything at the end f input that matches, which leaves the pointer is the same position for both expressions.

Comment: While ".*?" has a lower chance of horrible backtracking than ".*" it can still cause nasty backtracking if the input doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: Regexps with `.*?` will still cause issues in case backtracking buffer is overrun. Seen that many times. Lazy matching does not "fix" anything, a regex pattern must be "linear" to be effecient.

Comment: Note that the regex engine may have dedicated optimizations for specific sub-patterns. `.*` as a combination is common enough to justify such an optimization. For the given example. `^myname.*mahesh`, the `.*` will try to consume a `m` which is actually needed to match `mahesh`. A smart regex engine can store the location of that `m` and backtrack in a single step. Take a look at erip's answer which shows the formal steps. A regex engine which shortcuts the backtrack needs 18 steps instead of 28.

Comment: Note that non-greedy qualifiers can cause extra backtracking too in some circumstances. Consider `a.*bc` vs `a.*?bc` on `abababc`.

Comment: Note that regex engines that convert regular expressions to DFAs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) don't do any backtracking and are always fast, although they tend not to support some features like back-references.

Comment: Old thread but some might find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70443279/regex-ismatch-really-slow-when-doing-a-single-character-wildcard-search

Answer (score 26):

The following is output from the debugger.

[image: pattern 1]

[image: pattern 2]

[image: pattern 3]

The big reason for the difference in performance is that `.*` will consume everything until the end of the string (except the newline). The pattern will then continue, forcing the regex to backtrack (as seen in the first image).

The reason that `\s` and `.*` perform equally well at the end of the pattern is that the greedy pattern vs. consuming whitespace makes no difference if there's nothing else to match (besides WS).

If your test string didn't end in whitespace, there would be a difference in performance, much like you saw in the first pattern - the regex would be forced to backtrack.

**EDIT**

You can see the performance difference if you end with something besides whitespace:

Bad:

`^myname.*mahesh.*hiworld`

[image: bad]

Better:

`^myname.*mahesh\s*hiworld`

[image: little better]

Even better:

`^myname\s*mahesh\s*hiworld`

[image: Much better]

Comment: Just a side-note: There's something wrong about the implementation if it needs to backtrack. Popular reference is Russ Cox' notes on the implementation of regular expressions.