# Regex IsMatch really slow when doing a single character wildcard search

Tags: c#, regex, performance

We have a situation where doing a wildcard search with single character at the start and then other characters after the wild card and it runs incredibly slowly (in c# at least).
Is there a reason for this and a way to improve things?  Its quicker in almost all other cases.

examples for a 20k long random string run 1000 times:

- a.*r1    time taken: 1802
- r1.*a    time taken: 9
- r1.*b.*c time taken: 9
- r1f.*b.*c    time taken: 16
- a.*r1f.*c    time taken: 3199
- a.*r1.*c time taken: 1895
- a.*b.*r1f    time taken: 55450

Its definitely not the random string, as have tried different ones.

The pattern is definitely that if the first part is a single character followed by any characters after the wildcard, its always much much slower.

--Update--

I wonder if the way Regex works is that it loops through looking for that single character, and when it finds it, it searchs till then end looking for the next pattern. When it doesn't find it it goes back to that first character and starts looking for the next first character till it finds the first match again and does the some full logic, even though it could skip all those characters it passed on the first run.

I think I have confirmed this by generating a random string without character "a" - if I then use this character as the first character its really quick, but if I use "c" its slow. i.e. a.*b.*r1f is instant in that case but c.*b.*r1f takes a very long time.

If so wonder if you can optimise this in regex somehow?

Comment: You aren't doing a single character wildcard search in any of these. A single character wildcard search would simply be `.` (and if it's optional `.?`), not `.*` (which matches any character zero or _more_ times).

Comment: Thats right - its not a single character.  Effectively we are looking for a [anything in between] then r1 (in first example)

Comment: Then shouldn't that be a non-greedy wildcard search `.*?`?

Comment: Perhaps thats the answer - I don't really know what that means though - do I literally do .*? instead of .*

Comment: Well, I don't know if it will fix the speed or not, but your regex as it stands doesn't seem to correctly achieve what you set out to do. [`.*` test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=a.*r1&i=abcdefr1dfsdfsr1) vs  [`.*?` test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=a.*%3fr1&i=abcdefr1dfsdfsr1).

Comment: I will run some tests on it now - I am not sure the desirability of which of those results we want, but that would be an edge case and we would certainly take the performance if that fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately the performance is still just as slow.  That Regex storm shows the performacne issue though.  If you generate a random 20k string here: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/ and put it into your test and search for xyz.*x  and x.*xyz you will see the time taken is massively different

Comment: I see what you mean. That is very strange. If this is the extent of the complexity of your regular expressions, it might be more efficient to use `string` methods such as `.IndexOf`, etc.

Comment: Yup thats what I have done for now - in this very particular use case I do a different comparison, which is slower in general, but not 100 x slower.  I was keen to understand if it might be a bug or by design.

Comment: I wonder if the way it works is that it loops through looking for that single character, and when it finds it, it searchs till then end looking for the next pattern.  When it doesn't find it it keeps going through all the characters till it finds the first match again and does the some full logic, even though it could skip all those characters it passed on the first run.  If so wonder if you can optimise this in regex somehow.

Comment: I think I have confirmed this by generating a rnadom string without character "a" - if I then use this character as the first character its really quick, but if I use "b" its slow.

Comment: *it searchs till then end* - just wanted to point out that `.*` goes to the end and then comes backwards towards the start, trying to make a match - `.*?` will work like "searchs till then end".

Comment: I don't think you're being particularly fair to the Regex engine in your complaint though. I did your 20k into regexstorm; there are 316 occurrences of `a` and 4 occurrences of `r1` in my example. For starters that's practically 100x more occurrences the Regex could have to check (and your complaint is it's 100x slower).. For me `a.*?r1` was 12 ms (their inaccurate timings) and and `r1.*?a` was 1 ms. Maybe they  round up 0.01 to 1, but I can't see the orders of magnitude difference you do.. I'd put a lot of it down to "single char searches will hit hundreds more often than multi char do"

Comment: (Just did `a.*?A` for a time of 1 ms - server load probably has an influence on the timings too)

Comment: @CaiusJard just to be clear I am not complaining, I am trying to figure out the reason for this, and why it happens.  Regex is very impressive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this difference in performance lies in the way in which the search is optimized.

When a pattern starts with literal characters, a fast algorithm is used before the "normal walk" of the regex engine to find possible positions in the string where the pattern may succeed (positions where the literal substring is). Then the pattern is tested only at these positions by the regex engine.

This is the reason why a pattern that starts with the letter `a`, for a string (whatever the size) that doesn't contain the letter 'a' is quickly solved (no match, the whole pattern is never tested).

Now why for the same kind of pattern, one that starts with the letter `a` (only one literal character) and one that starts with `abcd` gives most of the time different performances in a random string. The answer is simple, positions with the four characters `abcd` are less frequent than positions with only `a`. Less positions to try => faster result.

---

Also note that a pattern like `a.*b.*c` is called a pathological pattern since it may cause a potential explosion of the number of backtracking steps. If using non-greedy quantifiers may sometimes reduce the problem, there's no guarantee that it improves always the performances (It isn't a magic wand). The best way is always to be the most precise with appropriate character classes, appropriate quantifiers,  and the most accurate description of the string, avoiding when possible `.*` or `.*?`. `a[^b]*b[^c]*c` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for that - so seems my assumption might be right then.  Appreciate your input - as that example you had did really speed things up for single characters.  However for multiple characters it doesn't seem to work - i.e. "g[^od]*?od"  doesn't return any matches for "goodod"

Comment: *`"g[^od]*?od"` doesn't return any matches for "goodod"* - indeed; why would it? "g followed by zero or more of anything other than o or d, followed by `od`" doesn't describe `goodod`

Comment: @tank104: it returns nothing because a character class is a set of characters (without any order) nothing more, nothing less, you can't put substring of several characters in it and expect that it will forbid the substring. No, `[^od]` matches all characters that aren't a `d` or a `o`. To forbid `od` between `g` and `od` the pattern is `g[^o]*(?>o(?!d)[^o]*)*od`.

Comment: But before all, you have to well understand how quantifiers work and what is the backtracking. It's really the most important.

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand backtracking now (and why the ? is important in *.? to limit it.  Also now understand why the [^od] doesn't work because as you mention its a set of characters, not ordered in any way.   Trying to best understand your solution though.  If I was to change the example to a 3 (or more) character search i.e. g*od12 in good1od12 would it be g[^o]*(?>o(?!d12)[^o]*)*od12 be a valid way to do that pretty efficiently?  (It works an is quick, just need to programmatically generate it in code now)

Comment: @tank104: its important to avoid to write things like `a[^b]*?b`. Really take the time to study that, if you can read the J.-F. Friedl book *mastering regular expressions*, it is better.

Comment: Your right - I do need to make sure I understand it properly so will do that.  Was just trying to get a solution in before xmas for a performance issue we are having.  Thanks